# Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**all im trying to do is download my Firestore data onto my tableview**

```
func loaddailymotivation() {

    FirebaseReferece(.MotivationDAILY).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in

        if let error = error {
            print("error getting MOTIVATIONDAILY DATA \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

        else {

            guard let snapshot = snapshot else { return }

        for allDocument in snapshot.documents {

                let data = allDocument.data()

                print("\(allDocument.documentID) => \(allDocument.data())")

                print("we have\(snapshot.documents.count) documents in this array")

                let dailymotivationTitle = data["Motivation title"] as? String
                let dailyMotivationScripture = data["motivation scripture"] as? String

            let newthought = RealMotivatioNDataModel(Realmotivation: dailymotivationTitle!, RealmotivationScrip: dailyMotivationScripture!)

            //self.motivationArray.append(newthought)

              }
            self.tableview.reloadData()

        }
    }

}
```

**not too sure why my app keeps crashing saying  Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file im going to upload a screenshot for more information**

```
import Foundation
 import UIKit


 class RealMotivatioNDataModel {

var RealmotivationTitle : String!

var realmotivationDailyScripture : String!

init(Realmotivation : String, RealmotivationScrip : String) {


    self.realmotivationDailyScripture = Realmotivation

    self.RealmotivationTitle = RealmotivationScrip
}
}
```

[this is the error im receiving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Qxzy.png)

Comment: At what line are you getting the exception?

Comment: Debug and try to figure out why your `dailyMotivationTitle` or `dailyMotivationStripture` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

**Reason:**

The exception is because you're trying to *force unwrap* a `nil` value.

**Solution:**

Use **`if-let`** to safely unwrap `optional` values.

```
if let dailymotivationTitle = data["Motivation title"] as? String, let dailyMotivationScripture = data["motivation scripture"] as? String {
    let newthought = RealMotivatioNDataModel(Realmotivation: dailymotivationTitle, RealmotivationScrip: dailyMotivationScripture)
    //add your code here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use force unwrap `!`  because  `dailymotivationTitle` or  `dailyMotivationScripture` may be `nil` and the reason is (`Key` may be not exit or this key value not `String`)

```
 let dailymotivationTitle = data["Motivation title"] as? String
 let dailyMotivationScripture = data["motivation scripture"] as? String
```

you can use `if let` or `guard  else`

```
guard  let dailymotivationTitle = data["Motivation title"] as? String,
       let dailyMotivationScripture = data["motivation scripture"] as? String
       else { return }
```

And `RealMotivatioNDataModel` will be like that

```
  let newthought = RealMotivatioNDataModel(Realmotivation: dailymotivationTitle, RealmotivationScrip: dailyMotivationScripture)
```

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers are generally correct about how to prevent your code from crashing, they don't explain *why* you're getting a crash because your var is nil.

What's happening here is the code iterates over all of the documents contained within the snapshot

```
for allDocument in snapshot.documents {
```

and this next line is attempting to read a field called 'Motivation title' within each document. The as? tells your code that if the field doesn't exist, set the var dailymotivationTitle to nil (? means it's an optional; it may or may not exist)

```
let dailymotivationTitle = data["Motivation title"] as? String
```

and here's an **example** of what your structure may look like that would cause the crash:

```
document_0
   Motivation title = "Some title"
   motivation scripture "Some scripture"
document_1
   Motivation title = "Some title"
   motivation scripture "Some scripture"
document_2
   Motivation Title = "Some title"
   motivation scripture "Some scripture"
```

Things go along fine when reading document_0 and document_1 but notice document_2 accidentally has a slightly different field name: **Motivation Title** (note the upper case T in Title) and that's not what the app is expecting. So, the dailymotivationTitle var is set to nil as mentioned above.

Expanding on that, the field may not exist at all in one document within the structure which is the same result; a nil var.

Then this line is the culprit because it unwraps that optional var with !

```
let newthought = RealMotivatioNDataModel(Realmotivation: dailymotivationTitle!
```

The ! following the dailymotivationTitle var tells your code that you GUARANTEE it's not going to be nil. But.. it was... so it crashes.

So hop into your Firebase Console and review the structure - you'll find that either one document has a field that spelled differently, or that field is missing entirely (or something else, but that's where to start)